# How to build URI with parameters properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to build URI for address like

```
http://example.org/controller?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

with a controller path variable

```
controller_path = example.org/controller
```

And an array with flexible size

```
params = {:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2'}
```

How to properly build URI by own class methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
controller_path(:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2')
```

or

```
controller_path(params) # in your case
```